# Magento changing URLs

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, magento, mod-rewrite

I am on Magento 1.9.2.1
my config is ok, that is

```
http://www.example.com/wholesale/
```

for secure and unsecure versions of url.

My Magento installation exists in subdirectory `/tempsite` and can be accessed as

```
http://www.example.com/tempsite/
```

I tried using

```
RewriteRule ^tempsite$ http://www.example.com/wholesale$ [R=301,L]
```

but not it's working, rather it messes up the site, 
my ultimate goal is to show my `/tempsite` as `/wholesale`

I am very weak at htaccess rules, any help is highly appreciated..
Thanks

**PS**
renaming the directory folder name is not an option for me

Comment: Just the `^` and `$` characters are wrong there, now it would need an exact match where the entire URL would read `tempsite` - which it never will - it will have some protocol and server at the start and some slash and perhaps subdirectory at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to going to the dashboard -> Catalog -> URL Rewrite Management?

There you can add a new rule and if you choose custom you can set what link to redirect.